# what is the .NET equivalent of @Deprecated in java?

Tags: c#, .net, metadata

Is there an annotation in .NET which allows methods or classes to be deprecated so that their use and their callers are identified by the compiler (cf @Deprecated in Java)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `[Obsolete]` attribute.

You can add a comment on what people should be using, for example:

```
[Obsolete("Use NewMethod() instead")]
public void OldMethod()
{
}
```

If you want to generate a compiler error when people use your method:

```
[Obsolete("Use NewMethod() instead", true)]
public void OldMethod()
{
}
```

This is an example for a method, but it can be used on almost any attribute target. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) for full docs.

---

Since the question was edited slightly, I'll add the VB.NET syntax as well, to cover the most common .NET languages:

```
<Obsolete("Use NewMethod() instead")> _
Public Sub OldMethod()
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that's a compiler warning, if you want an error just delete the function.

Comment: No, it's a compiler error. It's not the same as deleting the method, because software that was compiled against an older version of the assembly in question will continue to work with the new version of the assembly.

Answer (score 9):

[Obsolete] - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) for documentation on it. Adding this to a method or class will give a compiler warning if anyone tries to use it, with the custom message you give to the attribute if needed